# How can i remove something in module.exports, when it sent the "key"

Tags: javascript, java

So when my bot sent him the messaged of the "steamkey1" i would like that it removes the "steamkey1" so the next message he will sent when the bots needs to will be "steamkey2"

I have no idea how i can do it, or how i can explain it for finding it on google.

```
My module.export



module.exports = {

      Steamkeys: ["steamkey1","steamkey2","steamkey3","steamkey4","steamkey5","steamkey6","steamkey7","steamkey8","steamkey9","steamkey10"],
}



When it sent the message:

if(TradeType.includes("!buytf")){
        client.chatMessage(OFFER.partner, "Enjoy your Level Ups! ❤ \r\n Here is your free steam key! "+STEAMGAMES.Steamkeys[0]);
```

Comment: `Javascript` and `Java` are two very, very different languages. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

In one module you have the initial array of steamkeys and a function that removes and returns the first element any time it's called.

```
const steamkeys = ['steamkey1', 'steamkey2', 'steamkey3', 'steamkey4', 'steamkey5', 'steamkey6', 'steamkey7', 'steamkey8', 'steamkey9', 'steamkey10'];

export default function getSteamKey() {

  // `shift` removes the first element from
  // the array and returns it
  if (steamkeys.length) return steamkeys.shift();
  return false;
}
```

And in the other module you just call the function, and it will return each successive key.

```
client.chatMessage(OFFER.partner, "Enjoy your Level Ups!..." + getSteamKey())
```

```js
const steamkeys = ['steamkey1', 'steamkey2', 'steamkey3', 'steamkey4', 'steamkey5', 'steamkey6', 'steamkey7', 'steamkey8', 'steamkey9', 'steamkey10'];

function getSteamKey() {
  if (steamkeys.length) return steamkeys.shift();
  return false;
}

console.log(getSteamKey());
console.log(getSteamKey());
console.log(getSteamKey());
```

Comment: Nop this ain't it for me. My node instant crashed when i started it up.